# Querying Solr (Solr.net) with multi criteria query and localparams

Tags: solr, filtering, tagging, solrnet

I'm trying to do this:

```
http://solr:8080/solr/select/?q=name_make:[make]+name_model:[model]&rows=10000&wt=json&fq={!tag=dt}name_model:[model]&facet=on&facet.field={!ex=dt}name_model&facet.sort=count&facet.field.mincount=1
```

With solr.net - I have this:

```
var multipleQuery = new SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery(queryList, "AND");
var Facets = new FacetParameters();

Facets.Queries.Add(new SolrFacetFieldQuery(new LocalParams{{"ex", "dt"}} +"name_model") { MinCount = 1, Sort = true});

 List<ISolrQuery> filter = new List<ISolrQuery>();
 filter.Add(new LocalParams { { "tag", "dt" }, { "mincount", "1" } } + Query.Field("name_model").Is(NameModel));

var result = solr.Query(multipleQuery, new QueryOptions
                                                  {
                                                      FilterQueries = filter,
                                                      Rows = rows,
                                                      Facet = facets, 
                                                      Start = index
                                                  });
```

I expect something like

- make 1 [ ] 101
- make 2 [ ] 144
- make 3 [x] 232
- make 2 [ ] 32

But only get

- make 3 [x] 232

From my trace I see

- Solr  q (name_make:[make] AND name_model:[model] AND price:[0 TO 250000] AND year_registration:[0 TO 10000000])   0,023619    0,000006
- Solr  fq {!tag=dt mincount=1}name_model:A3

Am I missing a piece, or going about it the wrong way ?

Answer (score 0):

In your original query (at the top) you have `q=name_make:[make]+name_model:[model]` and below you have `name_make:[make] **AND** name_model:[model]`  so it could be an issue with your default operator. You can preserve this using SolrNet using the '+' operator instead of &&.

..`new SolrQuery("name_make:[make]") + new SolrQuery("name_model:[model]")`

.. will return you : `name_make:[make] name_model:[model]`

Where as ..

`new SolrQuery("name_make:[make]") && new SolrQuery("name_model:[model]")`

.. will return you : `name_make:[make] AND name_model:[model]`

Not sure if that's it, but something to try just in case.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try to pass the string arraty that contains multiple field names and search text in the below method. I will return the solrnet query for search with multiple filed name with OR condition.

public ISolrQuery BuildQuery(string[] SearchFields, string SearchText)
    {

        AbstractSolrQuery firstQuery = new SolrQueryByField(parameters.SearchFields[0], SearchText) { Quoted = false };
        for (var i = 1; i < SearchFields.Length; i++)
        {
            firstQuery = firstQuery || new SolrQueryByField(SearchFields[i], SearchText) { Quoted = false };
        }

        return firstQuery;
    }
```